# Can't install .Net framework 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework-version

I downloaded .Net framework 3.5.1 sp1  on windows server 2008 R2, 64 bit OS and every time i run the exe file i got an error message

> "You must use the Role Management Tool to install or configure Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" .

I started the Server Manager selecting the Features node and "Add Features" and enabled .net framework features but the error still occurred .

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/08/16/you-must-use-the-role-management-tool-to-install-or-configure-microsoft-net-framework-3-5.aspx

Comment: but I didn't install vs2008 the server only have sql server2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [How to install/enable .Net 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 for SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-server-2008-r2-environments.aspx)